# Is it possible to make screenshot of another app programatically via media projection api in latest versions of iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, permissions, android-mediaprojection, mediaprojection

I would like to ask if is possible to make screenshot of another app programatically via media projection api in latest versions of iOS and Android?
Or is it required root for that?
Thank you

Comment: Ok, where can I post this question if not there?

Comment: What do you mean by "make screenshot of another app"? The media projection APIs let you make a screenshot of the screen. Also note that the media projection APIs are an Android concept -- I do not know what iOS offers in this area (and this is why it is generally best to ask separate questions by OS).

Comment: It is possible to make a screenshot of the actual screen, at least for Android. I wrote such a solution as part of an app of mine. But banking apps, for example, can also prevent such a screenshot, if they are running in the foreground.

Comment: Do you think this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen can work for iOS ?